# Adding an extra padding to a div causing other divs to move down - CSS?

Tags: html, css, padding

I created a fiddle which is working fine but whenever I am trying to add an extra left padding to `lef-col`, the other two divs move downside.

What I am expecting is that padding applies to the inner content and the outer boundary of div, but in this case it looks like it is adding to the `div` calculation. Let me know what I understand incorrectly for passing.

PS - I fixed by applying `box-sizing: border-box` to `left-col` . I am looking for e.xplanation for this cause than solution(though alternate solutions are welcome too !!)

Code -

**HTML -**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="left-col">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos illum perferendis corporis, nemo dolorem, mollitia at sequi quis corrupti. Fugit eaque dolores inventore, aliquam quisquam, saepe officiis eos quia at!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="mid-col">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos illum perferendis corporis, nemo dolorem, mollitia at sequi quis corrupti. Fugit eaque dolores inventore, aliquam quisquam, saepe officiis eos quia at!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="right-col">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos illum perferendis corporis, nemo dolorem, mollitia at sequi quis corrupti. Fugit eaque dolores inventore, aliquam quisquam, saepe officiis eos quia at!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS -**

```
*, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {}

.container {
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.left-col, .mid-col, .right-col {
    width: 33.3%;
    float: left;
}

.left-col {
    background: lightpink;
}

.mid-col {
    background: lightgreen;
}

.right-col {
    background: lightblue;
}
```

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/km2brd8m/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add `box-sizing: border-box` to `left-col` it will work, and the reason is that when using `box-sizing: border-box` the padding is included in the set width.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/km2brd8m/2/)

---

You can also subtract the padding from the width using CSS Calc

```
.left-col {
    width: calc(33.3% - 20px);
    background: lightpink;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/km2brd8m/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Add the `box-sizing: border-box;` property to the three columns. This will include the padding it the overall dimensions instead of outside the original dimensions as it is currently doing.

Answer (score 1):

The `padding` increases the space used by the element, just like `margin`. `border-box` makes it use space from the element itself, instead of increasing its size.

You can read more about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/).